mlflow.exceptions.RestException: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Response: {'error_code': 'INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE'}
I am a newbie in this field,
I encountered this error and I have no idea on what I did wrong, I have looked up through the internet and seems like I am the only one who is getting through this.
so this is this is the error:
mlflow.exceptions.RestException: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Response: {'error_code': 'INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE'}
ERROR: failed to reproduce 'evaluation': failed to run: python src/cnnClassifier/pipeline/stage_04_model_evaluation.py, exited with 1

The code that raises the error:
evaluation.log_into_mlflow() 

in the stage_04_model_evaluation.py
I have already checked my mlflow_uri multiple times, deleted the existed models in the mlflow registry.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi @Daro ,You error shows that you are putting the invalid parameter value while trying to log information into mlflow .MLflow is rejecting those parameters as invalid. So there are some points we check to resolve this error first one is check MLflow URI sometime incorrect format can cause issues also check that you are passing to evaluation.log_into_mlflow() are correct and fulfill the criteria.If you need more help please provide the full code.thankyou
